# java odbc foxpro

Tags: java, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am attempting to build some java apps that use a FoxPro database that is part of a large Visual FoxPro product.  I have been able to read the data using a jdbc-odbc bridge.  While I had to search long and hard to find out how to accomplish that task, what I haven't been able to find out is if I can safely insert/delete/edit the tables.  I don't know if the index files are used by the jdbc-odbc libraries.
On a related note, does anyone know if you use MS SqlServer to set up a link to the foxpro data will make the FoxPro data "act" like a real relational db, or if the functionality doing things that way is the same as using the odbc solution.
I'm not replacing the current Visual FoxPro product, just trying to add some functionality, and I don't want to break the existing product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the JDBC-ODBC bridge handles indexes transparently, it wouldn't be much use otherwise.

You might be better looking at StelsDBF or Hxtt's native JDBC drivers.

Visual FoxPro is already a relational database. Not sure what you would achieve via the MSSQL approach.

Comment: I'd like to be able to use JPA and nice IDE things like creating entity classes from database, but those don't work (or at least I don't know how to do it) from a FoxPro database...